# SQL Command for removing characters like '!' or '*' from data in a MySQL column

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I suspect this to be a relatively easy fix for someone with a greater grasp on SQL.

Some of the data in the 'Name' field of my db have a '!' or '*' in the name, usually at the beginning of the name. I want to remove those unnecessary characters.

Is there an SQL command that will achieve such a lofty goal with alacrity and simplicity?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use MySQL [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function in a `UPDATE` query without any `WHERE` clause like this:

```
UPDATE tablename SET Name = REPLACE(Name, '!', '');
UPDATE tablename SET Name = REPLACE(Name, '*', '');
```

To do it in a single query, you can use this:

```
UPDATE tablename SET Name = REPLACE(REPLACE(Name, '*', ''), '!', '');
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed to do - to update the data so it no longer had the offending characters... Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(column,'!',''),'*','')
```

perhaps? See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Comment: Thank you for the link, Brad. I didn't know what I didn't know which was I needed to look for 'String Functions'.